# php echo not displaying

Tags: php, mysql

This code

```
<?php  echo "Likes: ".$r['votes_up']."&nbsp;"; echo "Dislike: ".$r['votes_down'].""; ?>
```

Wont post the values from the table for 'votes_up' 'votes_down' 
I cant get my head round this! Ive got this exact code working on a different page but it wont on this. 
Heres the entire code ....

```
    <div class="message">
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM threads WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'") or die(mysql_error());     
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql))  {
$posted = date("jS M Y h:i",$r['posted']); echo "".$r['author']." &nbsp; $posted";?>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-text="<?php echo "".$r['message'].""; ?>">
        Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<div class="message2"><?php echo "".$r['message'].""; }?></div> 
<?php  echo "Likes: ".$r['votes_up']."&nbsp;"; echo "Dislike: ".$r['votes_down'].""; ?>        
</div>
<br/>
<hr>
```

Can anyone help? its driving me insane

Comment: Hello [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: looking at your code, $r is out of scope where you refer to your problem.  place that echo inside the while loop

Comment: ARGHSQLINJECTION **why are people still failing at this in 2011?!**

Comment: Does echo only don't work with the db result or does echo don't work generally? Do you go through the while loop at least one? Hast the query a result (what is the value of $r)? Does echo work and the generated html code is broken? Why do you use double quotes around your variables, for example echo "" .$r[].""; ??

Comment: @sdolgy: It'll still exist. It'll just be the value from the last record. So it's "wrong", but I doubt it'd cause **nothing** to come out. PHP has no block scope like that.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal — Probably (at least partially) due to W3Schools (spit) continuing to teach PHP/SQL without mentioning SQL injection once.

Comment: @Quentin: Go go class action lawsuit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curly bracket is being placed before the last echo statement, therefore the $r variable is out of scope.

Move the } to later in your page like so

```
<div class="message">
<?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM threads WHERE id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'") or die(mysql_error());     
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $posted = date("jS M Y h:i",$r['posted']);
        echo $r['author']." ".$posted;
?>
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal" data-text="<?php echo $r['message']; ?>">
    Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<div class="message2">
    <?php
        echo $r['message']; 
    ?>
</div> 
    <?php
        echo "Likes: ".$r['votes_up']."&nbsp;";
        echo "Dislike: ".$r['votes_down'];
    } 
    ?>        
</div>
<br/>
<hr>
```

Also notice the call to mysql_real_Escape_string in the $sql var. this will prevent nasty sql injections

Comment: No, PHP has no block scope. That's not to say that this is correct, but it cannot cause "no values".

Answer (score 2):

Line 8 of your code

```
<div class="message2"><?php echo "".$r['message'].""; }?></div>
```

Why is that closing curly brace in there before the closing `?>` ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have closed the WHILE loop here:

```
<div class="message2"><?php echo "".$r['message'].""; }?></div>
```

Notice the curly bracket.

Therefore, votes_up and votes_down have no values.

Comment: No, they have values. PHP has no block scope. That's not to say that this is correct, but it cannot cause "no values".

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `$r['...']` variable is out of the scope where you place it.

Better way to do it (assuming you only fetch one row:

```
<?
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM threads WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'") or die (mysql_error());
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
?>

<div> ... </div>
<?php echo "Likes: " . $row['votes_up'] . " &nbsp;  Dislike: " . $row['votes_down']; ?>
```